# Fill Listbox when TextBox onkeyup event triggered

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, onkeyup

I have a TextBox where I'm supposed to enter the beginning of a city. When at least 3 characters are entered, I retrieve the possible list from a database (all cities whose name is starting with the entered string) and populate a listbox with possibilities. Then I expect to be able to choose from the listbox below and put the complete name in the TextBox.

So I have found a way here to trigger OnTextChanged TextBox event when onkeyup event occurs and I can populate my ListBox. When I click on a listbox item, the same event (from the TextBox) is triggered again and OnSelectedIndexChanged from the Listbox never triggered. See code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RefreshUpdatePanel(txt) {
        if (txt.value.length >= 3) {
            __doPostBack('<%= TextBoxCity.ClientID %>', '');
        }
    };
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCity" Width="185px" onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel(this);" OnTextChanged="TextBoxCity_TextChanged" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:ListBox runat="server" Width="185px" ID="Cities" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Cities_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:ListBox>


// this one fires when selecting entry in listbox

protected void TextBoxCity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load cities and populate listbox....
}

// I expect this one to fire when selecting entry in listbox

protected void Cities_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxCity.Text = Cities.Text;
}
```

Comment: Judging by what you're trying to do, is the AutoComplete feature of textboxes perhaps more suited to this task? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for your answer but this seems to be a windows form feature not available on the ASP.NET TextBox control, no ?